# Generic type conversion with template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am struggling to write a common interface for type conversion. I would prefer to achieve this via template specialization. My idea is to have a base template implementation to throw an exception i.e. in case no specialization is available. And user is supposed to provide every possible conversion.

I have a small implementation which of course is not working :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, typename F>
T convert(const F & from)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    throw ( std::logic_error("Conversion not implemented!") );
}

template<>
int convert<int, std::string  >( const std::string &  from) {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int a;
    std::string b = "hello world";
    const std::string &br = b;
    a = convert<decltype(a), std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_const_t<decltype(br)>> >(br);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I cant understand why the above piece of code is not working. I am removing const and reference from the `br`, so it should call the implemented specialization however it does not. I am looking forward to positive replies from you and also if there is more efficient way to call the convert API without specifying the types in template parameters.

Regards,
-Adnan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am removing const and reference from the br

Yes, but in the wrong order.

You remove before const and after reference; you should remove reference before and const after

```
// ......................................................VVVVVVVVV  reference before
a = convert<decltype(a), std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(br)>> >(br);
// ..................................^^^^^   const after
```

The point is that `decltype(br)` is `std::string const &`; I mean: `const` is applied only to `std::string`, not to `std::string &`.

On the contrary, the reference is applied to `std::string const`.

So when you apply `std::remove_const` to `std::string const &`, you get again `std::string const &`, because the full type isn't `const`.

Next you apply `std::remove_reference` to `std::string const &` and you get `std::string const`.

So the `const` remain.

If you use first `std::remove_reference`, from `std::string const &` you obtain `std::string const`.

Then you use `std::remove_const` (this time works, because the full type is `const`) and you get `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement, in C++20 will be possible to remove const reference with [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) exactly to combine `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference`:

```
a = convert<decltype(a), std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(br)>>(br);
```